# Android: How to get & set directory modification date

Tags: android, file, directory

I'm looking for a way to get a directories modification date. I've tried:

```
File dir = new File(myDir);
long mod = dir.lastModified();
```

But it's returning 0.

I'm also looking for a way to set the last modification date of a directory but haven't found anything.

Is there a documented way to do these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
Your code looks right, Just check the existence of directory..

```
public long lastModified ()
```

Returns the time when this file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, midnight. **Returns 0 if the file does not exist.**

So just check whether your file is exist or not..

**CODE:**

For get Last modified date from file,

```
File file = new File("Your file path");
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

To set Last Modified date to a file..

```
try{

    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/temp.txt");

    //print the original last modified date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Log.i("Original Last Modified Date : " , ""+sdf.format(file.lastModified()));

    //set this date 
    String newLastModified = "01/06/2012";

    //need convert the above date to milliseconds in long value 
    Date newDate = sdf.parse(newLastModified);
    file.setLastModified(newDate.getTime());

    //print the latest last modified date
    Log.i("Lastest Last Modified Date : ", ""+sdf.format(file.lastModified()));

    }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your myDir contains the path of directory

Following snippet works for me

```
        File file1 = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i("text", "" + file1.lastModified());
```

Answer (score 0):

The long variable returned by object dir needs to be converted like below, using your example.

```
File dir = new File(myDir);
long mod = dir.lastModified();
Date lastModify = new Date(mod);
```

For date setting, try function setLastModified( long Time ).

For reference, a Java link @ [Java 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)