# Java - set file creation date and time

Tags: java, file, datetime

I have found solution how to set last modified time in Java for specific file ([Android: How to get & set directory modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008775/android-how-to-get-set-directory-modification-date)).

Is there a way to set creation date and time in Java for specific file as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way. A Date contains an instant in time, with a millisecond precision. Just change the format used to parse the date. Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that.

Answer (score 3):

In java 7 it is possible to set creation time to directory or file using such code:

```
//date which is used as date of creation
Date creationDate;
//path to directory of file to which to set creation time
Path somePath;
...
FileTime time = FileTime.fromMillis(creationDate.getTime());
Files.setAttribute(somePath, "creationTime", time);
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but file creation time I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work on MAC for OSX a UNIX variant using HFS file system.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS;

class changetime{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Path p = Paths.get("./test.txt");
        System.out.println(p);
        try {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(2010, Calendar.MARCH, 20);
                Files.setAttribute(p, "basic:creationTime", FileTime.fromMillis(c.getTimeInMillis()), NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot change the creation time. " + e);
        }
    }//END Main

}//END Class
```

Comment: can you please provide NOFOLLOW_LINKS