# Is it possible to create new file with some specific old date?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-cursor, android-date

In my Android application I have a feature of renaming files. I have implemented this feature by creating a new file with new name on same path and then copying the content of original file to new file after all that I delete the file with old name.

The problem here is that the timestamp of the original file is not retained and the renamed file gets created with time when it was renamed.

**What I have tried so far**

1- I used file.renameTo() function.

2- 1 never works so I used `setLastModified` method for new file and passed it the last modified date of original file. Got this last modified date by using `existingFile.lastModified()`.

3- After that in function where i am fetching files using Media Store I sorted the files by `DATE_MODIFIED`

4- Point 3 doesn't worked properly as it keeps showing renamed file on top with original file date, so I removed Sort by `DATE_MODIFIED` from media store and tried `fetchedFiles.sortByDescending { it.getMFileDate() }`

5- Point 4 also have same issue the renamed file shows up on top.

**Code for renameTo function usage that didn't work properly**

```
           try {

            val existingFile = File(selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path())
            val separator = "."
            val arrValues: Array<String> =
                selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path()?.split(separator)!!.toTypedArray()
            val newFileName = inputText
            val newFilePath =
                selectedFile.getMParent_file() + "/$newFileName.${arrValues[arrValues.size - 1]}"
            val newFile = File(newFilePath)
            existingFile.renameTo(newFile)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

*The above code renames the file on device version 8 but on Android version 7 it just removes the file. It doesn't shows up same results on different devices*

***Below is my current code:***

**Permissions**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**UPDATED [23-12-2020]**

*I have made changes to `proceedRenaming` function, first i created new file object then copied it, after that i have set lastModified and at the end Media Store scan is called.
This is the right call hierarchy. It works fine on devices greater than or equal to Android Version 8 (OREO).
I have figured out the `setLastModified`  function is not working on devices below Android Version 8 (OREO). It keeps on setting the current date to new file.*

**Rename Function**

```
 private fun proceedRenaming(
    context: Context,
    selectedFile: MyFileModel,
    positionOfDeleted: Int,
    inputText: String,
    isFileShortcutCreated: Boolean
) {
    try {
        //delete shortcut if exists
        deleteFileShortCut(context, selectedFile, positionOfDeleted)
        val existingFile = File(selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path())
        val separator = "."
        val arrValues: Array<String> =
            selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path()?.split(separator)!!.toTypedArray()
        val newFileName = inputText
        val newFilePath = selectedFile.getMParent_file() + "/$newFileName.${arrValues[arrValues.size - 1]}"
            val newFile = File(newFilePath)
            copy(existingFile, newFile)
            //print the original last modified date
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
            val date1 = "" + sdf.format(existingFile.lastModified())
            Log.d("Origina Date :", date1)

            //set this date
            //need convert the above date to milliseconds in long value
            val newDate: Date = sdf.parse(date1)
            newFile.setLastModified(newDate.time)
            //print the latest last modified date
            val date2 = "" + sdf.format(newFile.lastModified())
            Log.i("Lastest Date : ", date2)


            context?.sendBroadcast(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    Uri.fromFile(newFile)
                )
            )
        if (existingFile.exists()) {
            existingFile.delete()
            existingFile.canonicalFile.delete()
            if (existingFile.exists()) {
                BaseApplication.applicationContext()
                    .deleteFile(existingFile.getName())
            }
        }
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context,
            arrayOf<String>(selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path().toString()),
            null
        ) { path, uri ->
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned $path:")
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=$uri")
            context?.contentResolver
                ?.delete(uri, null, null)

        }

        selectedFile.setOldFileName(selectedFile.getMFile_name()!!)
        selectedFile.setOldFileParentFileh(selectedFile.getMParent_file()!!)
        selectedFile.setOldFilePath(selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path()!!)
        selectedFile.setMAbsolute_path(newFilePath)
        selectedFile.setMFile_name(newFileName)
        selectedFile.setPosition(positionOfDeleted)
        renamedFile.postValue(selectedFile)
        if (isFileShortcutCreated) {
            createFileShortCut(context, selectedFile, positionOfDeleted)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            context?.getString(R.string.text_rename_error),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

**Copy Function**

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun copy(src: File?, dst: File?) {
        val inStream = FileInputStream(src)
        val outStream = FileOutputStream(dst)
        val inChannel: FileChannel = inStream.getChannel()
        val outChannel: FileChannel = outStream.getChannel()
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel)
        inStream.close()
        outStream.close()
    }
```

**Function Where I am fetching files from MediaStore**

```
private fun readFiles(
    args: Array<String?>,
    where: String
): ArrayList<MyFileModel> {
    val fetchedFiles = ArrayList<MyFileModel>()
    var fileCursorExternal: Cursor? = null
    var fileCursorInternal: Cursor? = null
    try {
    //Tables
        val tableExternal = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
        val tableInternal = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("internal")

    //Column
        val column = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
        )

    //Sort by date
        val orderBy = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED

        fileCursorExternal = context.contentResolver.query(
            tableExternal,
            column,
            where,
            args, "$orderBy DESC"
        )
        while (fileCursorExternal!!.moveToNext()) {
            fetchedFiles.add(setMyFileModel(fileCursorExternal))
        }


        fileCursorInternal = context.contentResolver.query(
            tableInternal,
            column,
            where,
            args,
            "$orderBy DESC"
        )
        while (fileCursorInternal!!.moveToNext()) {
            fetchedFiles.add(setMyFileModel(fileCursorInternal))
        }
    } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        fileCursorExternal?.close()
        fileCursorInternal?.close()
    }
    
    //fetchedFiles.sortByDescending { it.getMFileDate() } //commented as not working 
    return fetchedFiles
}
```

**Function Where the data from cursor is converted to MyFileModel class object**

```
private fun setMyFileModel(cursor: Cursor): MyFileModel {
    val MyFileModel = MyFileModel()
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            MyFileModel.setMFileDate(
                getReadableDate(
                    cursor.getLong(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
                        )
                    )
                )
            )

            MyFileModel.setMAbsolute_path(
                cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
                    )
                )
            )
            MyFileModel.setMFile_name(
                cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE
                    )
                )
            )
            MyFileModel.setMFile_size(
                getReadableSize(
                    cursor.getLong(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            MyFileModel.setFileType(getFileType(MyFileModel.getMAbsolute_path()).name)
            if (MyFileModel.getMAbsolute_path() != null) {
                val file = File(MyFileModel.getMAbsolute_path())
                MyFileModel.setMParent_file(file.parent)
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return MyFileModel
}
```

**Function to convert long date to string**

```
 private fun getReadableDate(dateVal: Long): String {
        try {
            var date = dateVal
            date *= 1000L
            return SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(Date(date))
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return ""

    }
```

**Required Output**

1- On renaming a file, new file should be created old file should be deleted.

2- New file should have timestamp of old file so that sorting is not disturbed.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: `I have implemented this feature by creating a new file with new name on same path` That does not look like a good approach. Use the File:renameTo() method.

Comment: I agree, @blackapps, but the OP reports having tried that, and it didn’t work. Can we help making it work?

Comment: Shure. But i see no code. @Ole V.V.

Comment: @blackapps i have already tried renameTo method but its not working properly. I have edited my question and added the code i used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to get & set directory modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008775/android-how-to-get-set-directory-modification-date)

Comment: @ariefbayu I have updated my question. Please read UPDATED part. I have figured out setLastModified is not working fine on devices below Android Oreo.

Comment: I think you can safely ignore Oreo device as this is already old...

Comment: `val existingFile = File(selectedFile.getMAbsolute_path())` ? What is selected.File? And why that messing around with a new name which is hard to follow? Just add a new extension to the filepath and ready. And doesnt renameTo return a boolean?